# Change disabled output field to text with prefixt

Tags: javascript, css

My full code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/t3JCBRrX

I made an easy calculation script for my website. I'd like two modifications but I can't seem to do it.

This is what I have now:

**The function:**

```
    var ap,result;
    function setValue() {
    ap = Number(document.getElementById('ap').value);
    }

    function bereken(){
        setValue();
        result = (((ap*275)/(ap*275))*1200+(ap*275) || 0).toFixed(e);
        document.getElementById('e').value = result;
    }
```

**The form:**

```
<label for="e" id="answer">Kosten: </label>
         <input type="field" name="Antwoord" id="e" disabled><br>

        <input type="button" onclick="bereken()" value="Bereken">
```

I'd like to prefix the result with a euro sign (result is '€123' instead of '123'). 
I would also like the result to be just plain text, instead of a disabled input field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm just a beginner. Thanks!

*edit: the calculation is that complicated because I don't want the answer to be '1200' when '0' has been entered*

Comment: where u specified html tag that contains id value `ap`

Comment: try `readonly="readonly"` on your input field rather than `disabled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/w38umrex/)

Just insert the value with '€' appended

```
document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = '€'+result;
```

Also you can  change the disabled input to label if you want it to be plain text

```js
var ap, result;

function setValue() {
  ap = Number(document.getElementById('ap').value);
}

function bereken() {
  setValue();
  result = (((ap * 275) / (ap * 275)) * 1200 + (ap * 275) || 0).toFixed(e);
  document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = '€' + result;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='ap' placeholder='enter value' />

<label for="e" id="answer">Kosten:</label>
<label type="field" name="Antwoord" id="e" disabled></label> <br>

<input type="button" onclick="bereken()" value="Bereken">
```

Comment: using this line instead of mine: document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = '€'+result; gives me this result: 'â‚¬ 123' . using &euro; just shows &euro;

Comment: I must be doing something wrong... I'm sorry, this is my first interactive form. I added my entire code to the opening post

Comment: changed the euro sign to &euro; again, made a mistake before, works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. change `document.getElementById('e').value = result;` to `document.getElementById('e').value = "€"+result;`.
2. change `disabled` to [`readonly`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JS Code:

```
var ap,result;
    function setValue() {
    ap = Number(document.getElementById('ap').value);
    }

    function bereken(){
        setValue();
        result = (((ap*275)/(ap*275))*1200+(ap*275) || 0).toFixed(e);
        document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = result;
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
    <input type="text" id="ap"/>
    <label for="e" id="answer">Kosten: </label>
    <span>&euro;</span><span id="e">&nbsp;</span><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="bereken()" value="Bereken"/>
```